# Importance of change the Time Step Value for the Accuracy of a Transient CFD Simulation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, numerical-analysis

I have a transient simulation for a case from 0 to 3 sec , actually i interest the solutions on time range from 2 to 3 sec , as my velocity and mesh size , my time step should be 0.0000000001 sec , my question is can I make my time step is 0.0001 sec for time range 0 to 1.9 and the i use 0.0000000001 for time range from 1.9 to 4 sec ( the range i interested ) ? BTW I use ANSYS FLUENT as a commercial CFD software.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. Since the approximation error is simply accumulating during the time integration.

You can never compensate the errors you made earlier.

Thus, in terms of accuracy, this is not a good idea.

Comment: also if i have convergence on iterations for one time step ?

Comment: if not why FLUENT put time variable steeping method as option on time step ?

Comment: 1. No. Convergence in every time step only means that the algebraic error is small. This is independent of the approximation error.

Comment: 2. Variable time stepping uses heuristics to estimate the error and to use larger time steps where the error is probably small anyways.

Comment: Ok. I have boiling case , starting time the CFL=0 until boiling happen , so can I use different time step at each range ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. You can use different time steps. If there is a range where nothing changes, a large time step might be ok. The variable time stepping scheme should detect this.

Comment: so as your last comment , i can use time step for CFL=0 and another one on CFL>0 ? at same case solutions